# store variable value inside a if statement

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, storage

1st if condition:

```
if (currentQuestionIndex == 2) {
    var xvalue = currentscore;
}
```

2nd if condition: (**note:** current score increments for every `currentQuestionIndex`)

```
if (currentQuestionIndex == 5 && currentscore ==xvalue) {
    console.log('thanks for your participation')
}
```

I want to access the value of `xvalue` in 1st if condition and reference it in 2nd if condition. Is there any way to store value of a variable and reference it later without regards to if condition

Answer (score 2):

Just define the variable `xvalue` outside of `if` statement:

```js
///Just for testing
var currentQuestionIndex = 2
var currentscore = 2
///

var xvalue = 0;

if (currentQuestionIndex == 2) {
  xvalue = currentscore;
}

///Just for testing
currentQuestionIndex = 5
currentscore = 4
console.log('xvalue: ' + xvalue)
///

if (currentQuestionIndex == 5 && currentscore == xvalue) {
  console.log('thanks for your participation')
  ///Just for testing
  console.log('xvalue: ' + xvalue)
  ///
}
```

And read about variable scopes, for example [*here*](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp).

Comment: i did try this, but here currentscore gets incremented as currentQuestion index increase and is not constant. So for currentQuestionindex, other than two , it is returning zero

Comment: @eggsy I just answered your question: _Is there any way to store value of a variable and reference it later without regards to if condition?_

Comment: Consider xvalue= 2 in 1st if condition , it is referencing to xvalue =0(Global variable) in second if condition, which is not what i am expecting

Comment: @eggsy Here I added code snippet and some testing variables. It works fine: xvalue = 2

Comment: thanks for your effort. current score is not fixed. In this case it is assigned to two . A more probabilistic current score would be two for current index==2 and may be four for currentQuestion ==5.        Current score increments if a user gives right answer(which is not specified here).   My problem is current score updating once it reaches currentQuestionIndex == 5 , so x value is turning into four instead of two

Comment: @eggsy I changed the snippet so when `currentQuestionIndex = 5` the value of `currentscore` is `4`. But the code still outputs `xvalue: 2`.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is the link to my code .         https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-9chho4vs0FS3BaSFZvaU1lc1E                                                                  Here in this file i am trying to reference x value in if(currentQuestionindex == 5 && currentScore = xvalue). It is saying xvalue is out of scope and not executing if condition. This code in run in amazon lamba

Comment: @eggsy you are accessing it before you've defined it, as on this [screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/5Idnx). Try to define it somewhere earlier.

Comment: thank you. I did try to define it here. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-9chho4vs0FeFhqNU0ybno0NHM                                               The if statement is still not working. I declared xvalue to undefined before the if statements. It is storing xvalue when currentQuestionindex ==2 and delivering xvalue score when index ==2 but when i tried to use it for any other current index. It is returning undefined as how i initialized before the if statements.
ps: I checked the value of xvalue in line 496 by terminating if statement without end and outputting it at the system print screen

Comment: i made my question more clear here.  your code snippet works fine, but i dont understand why is it not working in my case...........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210109/value-returning-undefined-if-the-if-condition-is-not-met?noredirect=1#comment71581472_42210109

Comment: I defined a global variable outside all of my functions and it is working fine. Thanks for your help :) :)

Comment: @eggsy Happy that helped you. If the answer was helpful... [http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you **can** access a variable declared with `var` inside `if` statement. A `if` block (or any block) does not create a new scope: in JavaScript, only a *function* do that.

This is **valid** (example from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types#Variable_scope)):

```
if (true) {
  var x = 5;
}
console.log(x);  // x is 5
```

This happens because JavaScript interpreter *scans* your function before executing it, and keep track of all variable declarations (like moving it to the top).

So, the above code is equivalent to (interpreter perspective):

```
var x;

if (true) {
  x = 5;
}
console.log(x);  // x is 5
```

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_Types#Variable_scope):

> JavaScript before ECMAScript 2015 does not have **block** statement scope;
>   rather, a variable declared within a block is local to the function
>   (or global scope) that the block resides within.

As pointed, this behavior changes with the introduction of ECMAScript 2015 [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

```
if (true) {
  let x = 5;
}
console.log(x);  //x is not defined
```

So, to use your code as an example, this will run fine:

```
/* arbitrary values */
var currentQuestionIndex = 2;
var currentscore = 10;

if (currentQuestionIndex == 2) {
    var xvalue = currentscore; //declared inside if block
}


if (currentQuestionIndex == 2 && xvalue == 10) { //I can read here
    console.log('value of xvalue: ' + xvalue); //can read here too: will print 10
    console.log('thanks for your participation')
}
```

Anyway, just because you **can**, doesn't mean you **should**. As a matter of readability and code organization, a recommended practice is to declare your variable at the beginning of your scope (*global*, if outside any function, or *local*, if inside a function).

Comment: Here currentscore gets incremented as currentQuestion index increase and is not constant.  current score is defined based on input given by the user. If the answer is correct, it is incremented by one.

Comment: @eggsy yes, it was just to demonstrate how scope works

Comment: @eggsy Maybe your problem is other than variable scoping.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your `xvalue` variable outside of your if statement.

`var xvalue = 0;`

or simply:

`var xvalue;`

This way the variable is always able to be accessed by any other function, even if you haven't given it a value.

Comment: i did try this, but here currentscore gets incremented as currentQuestion index increase and is not constant. So for currentQuestionindex, other than two , it is returning zero or undefined

Answer (score 0):

Just declare `xvalue` outside the first `if` like this:

```
var xvalue; // decalare it here so it can be accessed by both if statements (probably you'll have to initialize it with something)
if (currentQuestionIndex == 2) {
    xvalue = currentscore; // don't redeclare it here so you won't shadow the above one
}
```

Read more about **scopes**, **variables lifetime** and **shadowing**!

Comment: i did try this, but here currentscore gets incremented as currentQuestion index increase and is not constant. So for currentQuestionindex, other than two , it is returning undefined

Comment: @eggsy You'll have to initialize the `xvalue` like this: `var xvalue = 0`.